# Como criar carrinho de compras em JSF com Hibernate Postgres Glassfich e primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hibernate

Preciso criar um carrinho de compras como num *e-comerce* porém tudo na mesma Pagina, e não sei nem por onde começar, sou novo em programação estou com muitas duvidas.

No meu projeto uso *Primefaces*,*Postgressql*,*Hibernate*, o projeto é *JSF* e tem o cadastro de produtos em que vão ser adicionado ao carrinho pelo usuário.

Comment: Aqui tem um curso que implementa o carrinho de compras: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB13j4x4QZE&list=PL_GwGUsBlNydMdSOh8nYYRwD4tvPX1EIV

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico no que você está com dúvidas? Do jeito que a pergunta está no momento parece que você quer ajuda desde a modelagem do banco de dados até a finalização do *front-end*... e aí provavelmente sua pergunta será fechada (como a [outra que fez](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85294/4808)) por ser ampla demais.